# managing multiple mixins - better with metaclass?

Tags: python, function, class, mixins, metaclass

I have a set of mixins that can be dynamically added to a BaseClass and mixed and matched.  They all share similar properties and methods, but should not override each other when multiple mixins are combined.  Is it better to build a regular class MixinManager to handle things or a MetaClass to change how my main BaseClass behaves based on which mixins are combined together?

For example, my mixins all redefine a `_full` method.  However, I want a single `full` method that calls whichever `_full` method is mixed into my base class.

## mixin classes

These mixins share common methods and properties.  I'd like to avoid overriding all the base methods in each mixin subclass.  It's a lot of repeated code.

```
import six
import abc
import inspect
import sys

class BaseMixin(six.with_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta, object)):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _full(self):
        pass

    # not working yet
    def has_name(self):
        return self._name is not None


class AMixin(BaseMixin):

    def __init__(self, db_name=None, **kwargs):
        super(AMixin, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.db_name = db_name

    def _full(self):
        print('i am an A mixin', self.db_name)


class BMixin(BaseMixin):

    def __init__(self, ext_name=None, **kwargs):
        super(BMixin, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ext_name = ext_name

    def _full(self):
        print('i am a B mixin', self.ext_name)


MIXINS = {name.lower().split('mixin')[0]: obj for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isclass)
          if 'Mixin' in name and 'Base' not in name}
```

## mixin manager class

I can get it kind of working with a regular class manager system.  However I will need to set many "manager" methods and properties and these seem like it will become unwieldy.  I don't want to hardcode define every method/property I need to do this for.

```
class MixinManager(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        mixins = [obj for obj in cls.__bases__ if 'Mixin' in obj.__name__]
        if len(mixins) == 1:
            setattr(cls, 'full', mixins[0]._full)

        return super(MixinManager, cls).__new__(cls, args, kwargs)

    def full(self, mixin=None):
        if mixin:
            assert mixin.lower() in MIXINS.keys(), 'mixin must be one of {0}'.format(MIXINS.keys())
            mix_obj = MIXINS[mixin]
            mix_obj._full(self)
```

## metaclass

This works when I only have one mixin (e.g. TestA, TestB), but fails when I have multiple Mixins (e.g. TestAB).  I can't get this working with the `full` method.  Is there a way to have a metaclass define a new `full` method on my class that controls how it's called on each instance?  I can't figure out how to properly do that.  I'm using `__call__` here because I wanted to control how the class is constructed when each instance is first called.

```
class MixMeta(abc.ABCMeta):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        return super(MixMeta, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('---')
        print('call mixmeta', cls, args, kwargs)

        mixins = [obj for obj in cls.__bases__ if 'Mixin' in obj.__name__]

        newclass = super(MixMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        if len(mixins) == 1:
            setattr(newclass, 'full', mixins[0](*args, **kwargs)._full)
        else:
            setattr(newclass, 'full', cls.full)
        return newclass

    def full(self, mixin=None):
        print('in full', self)
        if mixin:
            assert mixin.lower() in MIXINS.keys(), 'mixin must be one of {0}'.format(MIXINS.keys())
            mix_obj = MIXINS[mixin]
            print('mixobj', mix_obj)
            mix_obj(*self._args, **self._kwargs)._full()
```

## base objects

```
# mixmeta class
class BaseObject(six.with_metaclass(MixMeta, object)):

# mixin manager 
class BaseObject(six.with_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta, MixinManager, object)):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        print('in base object new first', cls.__bases__)

        return super(BaseObject, cls).__new__(cls, args, kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseObject, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class TestBase(BaseObject):
    pass


class TestA(BaseObject, AMixin):
    pass


class TestB(BaseObject, BMixin):
    pass


class TestAB(BaseObject, AMixin, BMixin):
    pass
```

Instantiating each class

```
base = TestBase()
a = TestA(db_name='dba') (would like name='dba'; maps to db_name)
b = TestB(ext_name='extb') (would like name='extb' ...)
ab = TestAB(db_name='dba') (name ambiguous; this maps to db_name)
ab1 = TestAB(db_name='dba', ext_name='extb') (same as above, both names map)
ab2 = TestAB(db_name='dba', ext_name='extb')
```

With the MixinManager, this works correctly.  With the MixMeta it fails to call properly.

```
a.full()  # should print from AMixin
b.full()  # should print from BMixin
ab.full() # should not print anything or throw ambiguity error
ab1.full(mixin='a') # should print from AMixin
ab2.full(mixin='b') # should print from BMixin
```

Similarly, I want to do the same thing with properties.  I'd like to map a generic `name` property to `_name` and it maps dynamically to whichever mixin is being called.  However, the names should not override when multiple mixins are combined together.

```
a.has_name()  # should find and print db_name from AMixin (only db_name set)
b.has_name()  # should find and print ext_name from BMixin (only ext_name set)
ab.has_name() # should print nothing or throw ambiguity error
ab1.has_name(mixin='a') # should print db_name (both db and ext names set)
ab2.has_name(mixin='b') # should print ext_name (both db and ext names set)
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I want to have a single method or property that calls the underlying mixin methods or properties depending on which mixins are used.  I don't know which mixins will be used ahead of time.

Comment: That's not the actual problem, that is a part of your solution.

Comment: Well, my issue is more a question than anything else.  Is it better to use a metaclass to dynamically manage my mixins or a regular class?  One problem is this line fails in my metaclass attempt, `mix_obj(*self._args, **self._kwargs)._full()`.  I can't figure out the proper way to call this.

Comment: That would be an opinion-based question. But in general you should consider that metaclasses with any kind of dynamic additions to classes increase the complexity, reduce the readability, prevent autocompletion in IDEs and make debugging much more complex. So, use that wisely!